# Why does colorbox close immediately on asp.net button OnClientClick event

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

In my asp.net page

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm2.aspx.cs" Inherits="QDCM.Site.Speaker.WebForm2" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title>Colorbox practice</title>
<link href="../Styles/css/colorbox.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="../Styles/js/jquery.colorbox.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function openColorBox() {
        $.colorbox({ width: "80%", height: "80%", iframe: true, href: "../QD/AddDocmnts.aspx" });
      }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="This should also work!" OnClientClick="openColorBox();" />

        <input type="button" value="this works!" onclick="openColorBox()" />

    </div>
</form>
```

this `<input type="button" value="open color box" onclick="openColorBox()" />` works fine, the [Colorbox](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/example2/) pops up correctly on html button `onclick` event

But, in this
`<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="This should also work!" OnClientClick="openColorBox();" />`
 
the asp.net button, it doesn't seem to work properly, 
the colorbox pops up and then auto closes immediately,

How can we use it then in asp.net button ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="This should also work!" OnClientClick="openColorBox(); return false;" />
```

This is to cancel the default post back of button